# Reading and displaying XML id attribute in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have written the following XML code:

```
<game id="1">
    <title>Call of duty</title>
    <release>
      <year>2007</year>
      <month>06</month>
      <day>27</day>
     </release>
    <publisher>Infinity</publisher>
    <engine>Source</engine>
    <platforms>
      <platform>Windows</platform>
      <platform>Xbox</platform>
      <platform>wii</platform>
    </platforms>
 </game>
```

I'm trying to display the game's id which in this case is number 1. How would I be able to do so? I have written the following XSL code:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="game"/>

<xsl:template match="game">
  Game: <xsl:value-of select="//game/@id"/>
  <br />
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you

Comment: Your XSLT code does not work or is incomplete (or both). `xsl:apply-templates` must be inside `xsl:template`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply with

```
<xsl:template match="game">
  <xsl:text>Game: </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
  <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

When you match *game* you are already in the node so there is no need to specify it again in the path.

Comment: You could use `xsl:text` to output text in a more controlled way.